# C# - Auto-check items in checkedlistbox when specific item is checked

Tags: c#, charts, checkedlistbox

I have a checkedlistbox in my program that allows the user to control which of 9 possible series are enabled on the graph. I have made it so only two series can be enabled on the graph at any one time using the following code:

```
//if there are two checked items
if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked && chListBoxChartSeries.CheckedItems.Count >= 2)
{
    //new item cannot be checked
    e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;
}
```

This works fine. However myself and my end user have discovered that one particular series (checkedlistbox and chart series index 2) doesn't really have any meaning unless it is displayed compared to two other series (indices 3 and 4).
I've had a go at trying to change the above code to recognize that the item at index 2 is checked and to allow me to - or even automatically - check the items at the related indices.
Full function shown below:

```
    private void chListBoxChartSeries_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        int indexA = 2;
        //specify indexes for related parameters
        int indexB = 3;
        int indexC = 4;
        //give positive checkstate
        CheckState autochecked = CheckState.Checked;

        if (chListBoxChartSeries.CheckedItems.Contains(chListBoxChartSeries.Items[indexA]))
        {
            //do not limit number of checked items
            //apply checkstates to items at this index
            chListBoxChartSeries.SetItemCheckState(indexB, autochecked);
            chListBoxChartSeries.SetItemCheckState(indexC, autochecked);
        }
        else //does not contain item at index 2
        {
            //if there are two checked items
            if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked && chListBoxChartSeries.CheckedItems.Count >= 2)
            {
                //new item cannot be checked
                e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;
            }

        }
    }
```

This has thrown all kinds of errors at me, although none of them have been particularly informative and the answers I've found to them on this forum don't seem to relate to my issue!
I don't really know how far off I am from achieving what I'm trying to achieve, so any words of advice or points in the right direction would be a massive help!

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating an infinite loop here. When you select item 2, it's not immediately added to `chListBoxChartSeries.CheckedItems` until some time after this method is finished. Therefore, it won't run the first part of your `if` statement on the first iteration, so items 3 and 4 won't automatically get checked.

Later, when you manually select, say, item 3, it *will* run the first part. However, once it gets to `chListBoxChartSeries.SetItemCheckState(indexB, autochecked);`, it triggers the event again. It will get as far as the same line, and repeat the process indefinitely.

Here's a rough version that should be closer to what you need. It's a bit rushed, so I'm sure you'll need to tidy up the logic a bit:

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    int indexA = 2;
    //specify indexes for related parameters
    int indexB = 3;
    int indexC = 4;
    //give positive checkstate
    CheckState autochecked = CheckState.Checked;

    if (e.Index == indexA && !chListBoxChartSeries.CheckedItems.Contains(chListBoxChartSeries.Items[indexA]))
    {
        //do not limit number of checked items
        //apply checkstates to items at this index
        chListBoxChartSeries.SetItemCheckState(indexB, autochecked);
        chListBoxChartSeries.SetItemCheckState(indexC, autochecked);
    }
    else //does not contain item at index 2
    {
        //if there are two checked items
        if (chListBoxChartSeries.CheckedItems.Contains(chListBoxChartSeries.Items[indexA]) && !(e.Index == indexB || e.Index == indexC))
        {
            if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked && chListBoxChartSeries.CheckedItems.Count >= 2)
            {
                //new item cannot be checked
                e.NewValue = CheckState.Unchecked;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've tested this and it seems to work initially, I'm sure I'll be able to clean up any problems it throws at me from here on out! Thank you @MichaelMcMullin